# Convert API errors codes to exceptions

Tags: php, api, exception

I'm working on a PHP interface to some API which can return many (up to one hundred) different error codes. My interface is supposed to throw an exception when such a code is encountered. My PHP is a bit rusty, therefore I'm unsure what would be the most suitable option for a present day php programmer:

- have a separate `MyApiThisAndThatError` class for each error code?
- or have a generic class `MyApiError` and provide API error code as an argument?

I'm also open to alternative suggestions.

Comment: If the error codes can be grouped logically (f.e. login errors, syntax errors in API queries, …), then that might justify accordingly named exception classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR:** *Use a generic MyApiException class that includes the API Error code.*

Ralph Schindler wrote a nice article on the general topic at http://ralphschindler.com/2010/09/15/exception-best-practices-in-php-5-3

If you read the whole thing, you will see a section **Best Practices In Library Code** that demonstrates (I've modified his example for this context):

```
// usage of bracket syntax for brevity
namespace MyCompany\Component {

    interface Exception
    {}

    class MyApiException 
        extends \RuntimeException 
        implements Exception
    {}

    class Component
    {
        public static function doSomething()
        {
            $myApiCall->doSomthing();
            if ($myApiCall->hasError) {
                throw new MyApiException($myApiCall->getMessage(), $myApiCall->getErrorCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming the above code, if one were to execute MyCompany\Component\Component::doSomething(), the exception that is emitted from the doSomething() method can be caught by any of the following types: PHP’s Exception, SPL’s RuntimeException the component’s MyCompany\Component\MyApiException, or the component’s MyCompany\Component\Exception. This affords the caller any number of opportunities to catch an exception that emanates from a given component within your library, that is instigated by the API Error returned. Furthermore, by analyzing the types that make up the exception, more semantic meaning can be given to the exceptional situation that just occurred.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. When I did it, I divided up all the errors into families (i.e Query, Model, Controller, Form, etc...), then within each error family, I had defined constants for each error code.

Ideally, I wanted to have a unified exception class, but there where certain points where I would have a set of function calls within a try catch block, and it was better to have them divided up into different families so I could do a catch for each error family, that would the appropriately determine what to do next. Yes, I could have had a unified error catcher and a function to determine the family from the error number, but it seemed so less elegant.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, "elegant" is the key word.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on few factors. In my opinion these are the reasons for specific exceptions:

1. You can logically group errors and logically name exceptions.
2. Errors have additional data that depends on error type (you can store this additional data and users can acces them nicely with set/get).
3. New error types are added very rarely (but you can always throw some base generic exception for unknown error codes).
4. Meaning of errors change in time (users of your interface will base on exception type, not underlying error code).
5. You are ready to properly document your specific exceptions so the users won't have to lookup API documentation based on underlying error code.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable.